# Fixing Responsive Design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I wrote the following code to display footer items in a certain way on a LARGE screen (>800px). It works correctly on a large screen, but now this setting applies to smaller screens, too (< 800px screen). I want to apply this flex setting ONLY to large screens... what am I doing wrong here?

```css
@media (min-width: 800px) {
   :root {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  footer .container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-end;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 599px) {
   :root {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 799px) {
   :root {
    font-size: 17px;
  }
}
```

Comment: rewrite this part: `footer .container {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
   align-items: flex-end;
   }` for smaller screens too

Comment: I did try that, but it didn't make any change.

Comment: Can you provide more details about the problem? That would help thanks

Comment: Also based on how I understand your problem. I think trying to remove the min-width for small devices will help. @media only screen and (max-width: 799px)

Comment: You could add in more code (html and css) for the problem to be more easy to be interpreted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that you have added meta tag in `<head>` :

This is important. Because without viewport tag media queries don't work at all.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Wow - this was why. Thank you so much! Also big thanks to all others who have contributed!

Answer (score 0):

If the settings you are applying in `@media (min-width: 800px)` are applying to smaller screen sizes that mean you have the same code written outside your query too. You should check it in the CSS file. maybe you wrote the same code below the query somewhere.

So check if this code is being used outside the `media query` and if it's been used outside the `media query` check its order is below the `@media 800px`
then you need to remove it and the code will work just fine.

Also, I would appreciate more CSS and HTML to work with

this is the code you should check if it's written outside your query.

```
footer .container {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: flex-end;
          }
```

---

If that does not work please provide us more HTML and CSS because it may be a CSS specificity issue.